# How can I get the color for a themed tabsheet

Tags: delphi, themes, ttabsheet

How can I determine the background color of a TTabSheet when running on a OS with themes like XP and above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try [GetThemeColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773397%28VS.85%29.aspx).

**Edit:** But note that tab sheets have a gradient under standard XP theming, so a single color probably is *not* what you need.

Comment: Thanks, although it is not what I want to hear. I placed a TForm on this tabsheet and would change the color of it to the color of tabsheet. After your answer, I think it is easier to make the form transparent.

Comment: And when I use TFrame instead of TForm it works like I wish (after a first look).

Comment: Frames have their problems, but I think they are just better suited as "subforms" than TForms are. (Probably because that's their reason of being. :-))